# flutter on iOSX chrashes

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

```
flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
⣟Unhandled exception:
Crash when compiling null,
at character offset null:
Not implemented
#0      TypeBuilderComputer.visitInvalidType (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/type_builder_computer.dart:58:5)
#1      InvalidType.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:7302:42)
#2      SourceLoader.computeTypeBuilder (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:1262:17)
#3      ClassHierarchyNodeBuilder.inferMixinApplication (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/class_hierarchy_builder.dart:2272:28)
#4      ClassHierarchyNodeBuilder.build (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/class_hierarchy_builder.dart:1445:7)
#5      ClassHierarchyBuilder.build (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/class_hierarchy_builder.dart:603:14)
#6      SourceLoader.buildClassHierarchy (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:1123:46)
#7      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:351:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart)
#9      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
#10     KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:326:12)
#11     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:269:52)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart)
#13     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:46)
#14     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:223:31)
#15     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:19)
#16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#18     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
#19     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
#20     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:12)
#21     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:206:20)
#22     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:69:46)
#23     FrontendCompiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:524:59)
#24     new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:175:37)
#25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
#26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#27     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#28     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
#32     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
#33     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
#34     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)


#0      TypeBuilderComputer.visitInvalidType (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/type_builder_computer.dart:58:5)
#1      InvalidType.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:7302:42)
#2      SourceLoader.computeTypeBuilder (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:1262:17)
#3      ClassHierarchyNodeBuilder.inferMixinApplication (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/class_hierarchy_builder.dart:2272:28)
#4      ClassHierarchyNodeBuilder.build (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/class_hierarchy_builder.dart:1445:7)
#5      ClassHierarchyBuilder.build (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/class_hierarchy_builder.dart:603:14)
#6      SourceLoader.buildClassHierarchy (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:1123:46)
#7      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:351:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart)
#9      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
#10     KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:326:12)
#11     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:269:52)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart)
#13     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:46)
#14     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:223:31)
#15     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:19)
#16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#18     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
#19     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
#20     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:12)
#21     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:206:20)
#22     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:69:46)
#23     FrontendCompiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:524:59)
#24     new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:175:37)
#25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
#26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#27     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#28     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
#32     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
#33     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
#34     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
⣯the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

Somebody has an idea for the solution

**An flutter doctor said:**

Franks-MBP:myfirst_osxApp frankmoos$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
• Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/frankmoos/flutter
• Framework revision 7891006299 (3 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
• Engine revision ae90085a84
• Dart version 2.10.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/frankmoos/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
• All Android licenses accepted.

**myfirst_osxApp frankmoos$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
• Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/frankmoos/flutter
• Framework revision 7891006299 (3 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
• Engine revision ae90085a84
• Dart version 2.10.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/frankmoos/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
• CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin installed
• Dart plugin version 201.9317
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.1)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
• Flutter plugin installed
• Dart plugin version 203.6912

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 451D4829-34AE-4111-A534-BBE91AC65104 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!**